# Returning Three Values from a Method

Tags: c#, class, return

I have this solution I am working on and am trying to return userInput of 3 different 
questions to Main. This is what I have currently.

```
public static string GetInput()
{
    //declared variables
    string userInput;
    string outputTitle;

    Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
    userInput= Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter the Gas Mileage: ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();

    return userInput;


}
```

The way I have it set up I never get passed the ("Enter your name"); question. What is a better way to go about this?

userName = InputUtilities.GetInput(userName); //Error  2   No overload for method 'GetInput' takes 1 arguments

Console.Write("Your name is:{0}", userName);

Comment: what do you want this method to return?

Comment: This method is in a different class than Main. I want to get the name and return it to Main to be displayed. Then with age and then gas mileage.

Answer (score 9):

Use a class to define the input that you want to capture, and return that.

```
    public class UserDetails
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string Age {get;set;}
        public string Mileage {get;set;}
    }

    public static UserDetails GetInput()
    {
        //declared variables
        //string userInput;
        //string outputTitle;
        var userD = new UserDetails();

        Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
        userD.Name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
        userD.Age = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter the Gas Mileage: ");
        userD.Mileage = Console.ReadLine();

        return userD;
    }
```

EDIT: example using out parameters.

```
void Main()
{
    string name, age, mileage;

    GetInput(out name, out age, out mileage);

    //use name, age and mileage here.
}

public static void GetInput(out string pName, out string pAge, out string pMileage)
{
    Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
    pName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
    pAge = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter the Gas Mileage: ");
    pMileage = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me this! I am not sure that I am allowed to create another class for this project though. This idea works great if I am allowed to create another class.

Comment: Maybe I am calling it wrong                                           InputUtilities.GetInput(out string userName);
Console.Write("Your name is:{0}", userName);

Comment: Please show your code and the actual error message.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this forum..do I type the code in here?In this comment area I mean?

Comment: Edit your question and add the code that you are having issue with.

Comment: You need to specify out parameters for all three.  Please refer to the example I added above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return 3 values, you have to have 3 places to put them:

```
public static List<String> GetInput()
{
    //declared variables
    string userInput;
    List<String> userInputs = new List<String>();

    Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
    userInput= Console.ReadLine();
    userInputs.Add(userInput);

    Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    userInputs.Add(userInput);

    Console.Write("Enter the Gas Mileage: ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    userInputs.Add(userInput);

    return userInput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the values entered by the user for each question to the same variable. Each write overwrites the previous value, which means you should only be getting the answer to the last question ("Enter the Gas Mileage"). There are a few general ways to go about this:

1) Either append each successive answer to the same string (Not recommended).

2) Create some object to store all answers (either a class or a list).

3) Use out parameters.

Since the other two answers have already been explained, here's the out parameters:

```
public static void GetInput(out string pName, out string pAge, out string pMileage)
{
    // do stuff here ....
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for. Thanks. I am going to try this out.

Comment: This causes an error. The name 'pName' does not exist in this current context. This occurs when I pull it to Main. Do I have declare pName, pAge, pMileage?

Comment: How are you calling it?  You need to declare them in main, and use them as out parameters when calling GetInput()

Comment: userName = InputUtilities.GetInput(pName);
            Console.Write("Your name is:{0}", userName);

Comment: If I declare pName, pAge, pMileage in Main then the error is NO overload for method. Takes 1 arguments.

Comment: @floyd I added a full example using out parameters to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
public static object GetInput()
{
    Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
    var _name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
    var _age  = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter the Gas Mileage: ");
    vae _mileage = Console.ReadLine();

    return new { name = _name, age = _age, mileage = _mileage };
}
```

Or

```
public static dynamic GetInput()
{
    //declared variables
    dynamic userinputs;

    Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
    var _name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
    var _age  = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter the Gas Mileage: ");
    vae _mileage = Console.ReadLine();

    userinputs.name = _name;
    userinputs.age = _age;
    userinputs.mileage = _mileage;

    return userinputs;
}
```